# Committing Into the Database Trying to Change the Form a Different Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a classified model that is hook up to the student model in a way that it looks like this

classified.rb

```
belongs_to :student
```

in my student model it

```
has_many :classifieds
```

The classifieds table contain `a column for student_id`

when I head to the rails console

I can create a new classified for that particular student record by doing

```
Student.find(19).classifieds.create(:ad_title => "blah", :ad_content => "blah", :location => "blah")
```

The record automatically gets a student_id generated because it was created in the student standpoint.

Now the problem is I have a classifieds controller with a new and a create method and a new form in the view

I am creating a new ad in the classifieds standpoint here is the form

```
<div>
新广告: <br><br>

<%= simple_form_for @advertisement do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :ad_title, label: "Title" %><br>
    <%= f.input :ad_content, label: "Content"%><br>
    <%= f.input :location, label: "Location"%><br>
    <%= f.input :student_id, label: "Your Student ID"%><br>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add an Advertisement" %>

<% end %>
</div>
```

The problem is the student_id must exist in order for that particular record to show up in index and my users don't know their id.

How do I create a classified in the student standpoint using forms

I consider going to my students controller and adding a method like this

```
def create_classified_ad
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
     @classified = @student.classified.create(params[:classified])
end
```

I am using devise so there is user session? I don't know how sessions work entirely I want that particular student to be found after logged in and have that student create a classified ad with the inputs from the form so the record will be created correctly?

The question is more like how do you insert data using forms to a hooked up table correctly? (and not merely inserting data into a simple no relationship table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be passing the `student_id` from the form. If you have a devise session, you should have access to `current_user`:

```
def new
  @classified = current_user.classifieds.build
end

def create
  @classified = current_user.classifieds.build(params[:classified])
  if @classified.save
    # do something
  else
    # handle failure
  end
end
```

In the index, you can do this:

```
def index
  @classifieds = current_user.classifieds.all
end
```

All of this assumes you have a devise session. If not, just fetch the student like so:

```
@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
@classified = @student.classifieds.build
```

Set up a nested route for the classifieds under the user:

```
resources :users do
  resources :classifieds
end
```

This allows you to fetch the student from a `student_id` param. Your route would like this: `new_student_classified_path(@student)`.